# Magento - Grouping products in one category by other categories they are in

Tags: product, catalog, magento-1.7

I'm working on a magento site for a clothes designer and she wants products categorized in "collections". She also wants them categorized in clothing types such as shirts, dresses, pants, etc.

I've created a category called "Everything" with the collections as subcategories ("Spring 2012", "Fall 2012", "Spring 2013"). Every product goes in one of these categories.

I also have Clothing type categories "Shirts", "Pants", "Dresses" to name a few. They are all root categories.

The client requested that when you click on one of the clothing types, the products will be grouped by collection. So if I clicked on shirts, it would show all of the Spring 2012 shirts, then the Fall 2012 shirts, and then the Spring 2013 shirts.

I haven't been able to come up with a solution and can't find anything in the documentation for this and hope someone may have an idea or a direction to point me in. Thanks.

Comment: If you found an answer please share it or mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it natively. But as a non-code solution, you could just add an attribute to the products for "collection" - set that attribute to be sortable, then change the default sort attribute.

That way, your category would sort by season just by making a couple of admin edits.

You could implement a more sophisticated code based solution, but that would be beyond the scope of what I could answer here.

FYI. You should only have 1 root category per store group. I think you might have mixed up your terminology.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm working on attributes now. Can you also pull the label down for the attribute name as well? So I can divide the sections by the label?